# How to count unique dates in date ranges

Tags: sql

I have a table with bookings

```
id date_start   date_end
1  03.01.2022    03.02.2022
1  03.02.2022    03.03.2022
1  01.03.2022    10.03.2022
2  02.04.2022    04.04.2022
2  02.06.2022    02.07.2022
2  30.06.2022    04.07.2022
```

Here you can see every case when the date ranges intersect and not
I want to count unique days in those date ranges by id.
So for the first one it should be 67 days, for the second 34 days.

I know how to do it for each case individually
for the intersect case I would just take max and min dates and count the difference between them, for another case I would at first count the difference and then sum them. But I don't know how to separate these cases in the script

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: company's sql version. What can be useful is that it has the function to count the days between dates and can generate the list with dates from start to end date

Comment: 1) A DBMS is something like SQL Server, Oracle MySQL, PosgreSQL, etc. - "company's sql version" doesn't mean anything 2) Please update your question with the output you expect based on the sample data you've provided and explain the logic you are using i.e. "the first one it should be 67 days" - the first what and where are you getting 67 days from?

Answer (score 0):

If you want row wise difference try with below query

```
    select id,date_start,date_end,datediff(DAY,min(CONVERT(date,date_start,103)),
 max(CONVERT(date,date_end,103))) Diff
from YourTableName 
group by id,date_start,date_end
```

If you want Id wise try with below query

```
select id,datediff(DAY,min(CONVERT(date,date_start,103)),max(CONVERT(date,date_end,103))) Diff
from YourTableName
group by id
```

Comment: if your date format is '03.02.2022' need convert date format 'yyyy-MM-dd'